# Get row ID of an SQLite FTS3 table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, fts3

I have created an SQLite FTS3 table that I am using within the Android development platform (`target` is 2.2 and `minVersion` is 8). For example, I created the table as follows:

```
create virtual table person using fts3(first,last);
```

I know that when I insert data into this table, I `long` is returned, which is the row ID of the record inserted. How do I get the row ID from this table? If I perform:

```
select * from person
```

I get `-1` for `Cursor.getColumnColumnIndex("rowid");`. Also, `Cursor.getColumnNames()` only shows the two columns ('first' and 'last') and not the 'rowid'. Any suggestikns on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using:

```
select rowid,* from person
```

Rowid is a hidden field and is not included in "*".

Comment: This issue has been driving me crazy for 2 hours. Thanks